# Does physically removing GPL code relieve combined work from GPL publication requirements?

Tags: licensing, gpl, copyleft, mit, combined-work

Here's the scenario. Alice crafted a compression library and published it under GPL. Bob crafted a font processing library which uses pieces of code from Alice's library and ... let's call it *overly optimistically* ... published his combined work under MIT license. This is a problem for people who want to use Bob's library because having Bob's library means they will also have pieces of Alice's code and would have to release their source code.

Suppose Alice's code is not that precious and can be replaced with some new code (perhaps using another MIT-licensed library). Carol is willing to take Bob's (labeled as MIT-licensed) code and rewrite it such that it no longer contains Alice's code and then publish the result under MIT license and use the result under MIT license as well.

Does Carol's rework of Bob's code result in code free of GPL publication requirements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in:

> **rewrite** it such that it no longer contains Alice's code

It really depends on how how such rewrite is done. Translations are considered derived work, also in the case there there no common "*words*" between the two implementations.  So a **(strict) rewrite** is a derivation of original code, but a **reimplementation** is not (an implementation not inspired from original code and not copying the internal structure, API, etc.).

Note: API could be copyrightable (Oracle vs. Google on Java), and this will complicate things, but a simple interface with `compress()` and `decompress()` should not be a problem.

Answer (score 5):

**Note**: consider this answer a work-in-progress. After nice debates in comments and chat I see there is needing to provide references and explanations to many assertions.

---

Short answer: Carol has the right to do it and **new** font processing library can have a single MIT license.

Little bit longer answer: according to *copyright* law (note that even if GPL is a *contract* this distinction is - almost always - not applicable). **Knowledge** (seeing original GPL source code) **does not make your code derivative work**. It's an absolute **undebatable point**; ad absurdum imagine if after working for company X you can't write similar software for company Y because you *saw* X's source code. That's exactly your *market value* for company Y and any legal action against this is a severe infringement of  **labour's rights** (of course patented - not just copyrighted - code can't be rewritten).

In more simple terms, imagine you're a CS student in University and you extensively study Linux (or Minix) source code in your OS design course. You finish university and you decide you want to write your own (even closed-source!) kernel. For sure you will use concepts you learned studying Linux source code (concepts, not code). If those concepts are not patented (and I can't think about any patented code in Linux) then what you're doing is perfectly (and obviously) legal.

Easy and reasonable? There are few obscure points (and jurisdiction matters)...

Under [Trade-related Aspects of Intellectual Property Rights](https://www.wto.org/english/tratop_e/trips_e/t_agm0_e.htm) (TRIPS) agreement member states have to ensure that certain minimum standards are implemented into their national laws. Article 9(2) states that:

> Copyright protection shall extend to expressions and **not** to ideas, procedures, methods of operation or mathematical concepts as such."

This is similar to US point of view about copyright (even if even in US there have been cases against this rule) where same [concept is described](http://www.copyright.gov/title17/92chap1.html#102) as:

> In no case does copyright protection for an original work of authorship extend to any idea, procedure, process, system, method of operation, concept, principle, or discovery, regardless of the form in which it is described, explained, illustrated, or embodied in such work.

The EU approach (in directive 91/250/EEC) is that a computer program is original if it is the author's own intellectual creation. The work must not be trivial – the author must have expended some skill, labour, judgement, knowledge in creating it. Note that knowledge is associated to *author* and it's not a result because it's the important point of above paragraphs. US copyright law defines "derivative work" as:

> “derivative work” is a work based upon one or more pre-existing works, such as a translation, musical arrangement, dramatization, fictionalization, motion picture version, sound recording, art reproduction, abridgment, condensation, or any other form in which a work may be recast, transformed, or adapted.

As I said there are however obscure points. For example Pumfrey J. (UK High Court judge) in an April 1999 case (CFI vs. Tradition) said:

> It seems to be generally accepted that the "architecture" of a computer program is capable of protection if a substantial part of the programmer's skill, labour and judgement went into it. In this context, "architecture" is a vague and ambiguous term. It may be used to refer to the overall structure of the system at a very high level of abstraction...The term "architecture" may also be used to describe "program structure."

This decision has very big implications because (unless otherwise stated) copyright owner is employer (and not employee). It seems pretty unreasonable (to me) and against traditional concept of copyright, for example another 1992 UK sentence (John Richardson Computers) decided in the other way. It's still a controversial topic because it's against traditional copyright concept (developed in US courts, with few exceptions). Eric S. Freibrun well expressed this point:

> While a patent can protect the novel ideas embodied in a software program, a copyright cannot. Copyright protection extends to the particular form in which an idea is expressed. In the case of software, copyright law would protect the source and object code, as well as certain unique original elements of the user interface [...] In contrast with patents, independent development of a copyrighted work is a defense to an allegation of copyright infringement. Imagine, though, how unlikely it would be for the same thousands of lines of code to be created independently by one not engaged in unauthorized copying. Unlike patents, copyright law affords no protection to the ideas underlying the program. Ideas and concepts are fair game for competitors to the extent they are not protected by patents or trade secrets.

Please note that Freibrun introduced a fundamental point: trade secrets. They're (one of) the reason IBM won its copyright legal battle.

Because judgment is so often discretionary (at least in some countries) we have tools like CRD (but big companies can still push you in endless expensive legal actions). The point is that it has to be judged case-by-case in the light of the skill and labour in design and coding of source code to be *copied*. It is not determined by its importance or size nor by the amount of use in the system.

In short the question to answer is: "can you write such code by yourself even *if* you didn't see (this doesn't imply you really didn't) Alice's code?" If answer is *yes* (no matters code *quality*) then it can't be considered copyright infringement even when law is unclear (like in UK or in US when big companies are involved.) If you used *ideas* end *methods* then - in some countries - it may be controversial.

Comment: "*It's an absolute undebatable point*" all those many companies over the years that have paid for [clean room re-implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_room_design) to avoid exactly that problem - of re-implementation without contamination by the earlier code base - were utterly wasting their money, then?

Comment: MadHatter, _Contamination_ isn't right wording here. You need _clean room design_ if you have to demonstrate you didn't **copy** knowledge from closed-source code. When you have knowledge (because of crd or because of free open inspection of source code) then you can write your own code (free from copyright, if not patented). Difference _should_ be clear! Did you work from (let's say) Microsoft on Windows Kernel team. Are you free to use knowledge you gained in your own project (even open source) if you don't infringe any patent? Obviously yes.

Comment: It's hard to make a small peace of code _obviously_ different (that's why for copyright law speaks about it) but it's trivial for a larger code base (note emphasis on word _copy_, unless patented knowledge isn't protected by copyright law) because it's basic market value of any developer, mind this. That's why those absurd legal battles nowadays moved to patents...

Comment: The reason you don't want to copy knowledge from code is because it's covered by copyright, and that isn't inherent to closed-source code.  Inspection of the source code base risks the re-use of copyrightable concepts in the the writing of the replacement; if the license on the source code base doesn't permit that (which closed-source doesn't, and GPLed code only does if the resulting code is GPLed), you would need to avoid that, hence clean rooms.  As a passing note, making code obviously different isn't enough to avoid copyright infringement; it must be *completely* different, except where..

Comment: ... the function of the code means that form is implicit in function, so copying is unavoidable (see, eg, NEC Corp. v Intel Corp. (1990)).

Comment: You're talking about PATENTING. Copyright isn't about that. Legally speaking there is an enormous difference. Do you study Minix in university? Does it tie you to its license if you write your own kernel?

Comment: No, I am not.  Please read the linked wikipedia article; as it itself says, it's a "*method of copying a design ... without infringing any of the copyrights ... However, because independent invention is not a defense against patents, clean room designs typically cannot be used to circumvent patent restrictions*".  I'm afraid I'm beginning to suspect that your understanding of both copyright and patent law is at odds with the way it actually works, at least in the US and the UK.  I can't speak for Italian law, about which I know nothing.

Comment: MadHatter, exactly. Let's dissipate confusion. Clean room design can't help for patents. Good. Clean room design helps for copyright because you can _prove_ (but there are exceptions) that you didn't copy original source code. It's what we had when absurd and stupid legal battles were on copyright more than on patents. Good. Copyright does not apply to knowledge (whichever is the form you acquire it!!! reading original source code or doing reverse engineering). If you don't agree about this (please re-read examples I wrote in answer) then we can stop discussing because it's very basic point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36790/discussion-between-madhatter-and-adriano-repetti).

Comment: Please re-read carefully what c.r.d. is for. It's evidence you din't COPY source code (directly or indirectly through disassembling). You acquire knowledge and that's all. That's all because that's the only thing that copyright can protect you against. If you need to protect something (implementation? algorithm?) then you have patenting...

Answer (score 2):

If the GPL code is a clean, defined, module, and you remove every scrap of it, and replace it by some unrelated code, you're fine. People do it every day.

Answer (score -1):

**Alice sues Bob for violating the terms of the GPL.**

I am assuming here that Bob is linking to Alice's GPL library and using it for his project, but has decided to keep his own project under the MIT. The problem here is that the Free Software Foundation believes that linking to a GPL library is enough to make your project a "derivative work" and thus will require you to place your own project under the GPL.

Now, that is the Free Software Foundation's own interpretation of the GPL, and you could argue that this interpretation has no basis (as the law is silent on whether linking actually causes a project to be a "derivative work"). But that's why you need a court case to resolve the issue.

If Alice wins the lawsuit, then Bob has to relicense his code under the GPL, and we deal with the repercussions of this.

If Bob wins the lawsuit, then Bob is free to keep his project licensed under the MIT. This is clearly uncharted legal territory here (as it opens a major loophole that could render the GPL toothless), but it may render Carol's attempt to rework the project unnecessary. If Bob is able to still use GPL code while keeping the MIT License, then *anyone* (including closed-source codebases) can use GPL code in their project. There's no reason to remove the GPL code then.

I would argue that if Bob wants to actually produce permissive software without taking on unnecessary legal risk, he should either find a different compression library under a more permissive license OR do a clean-room implementation of Alice's code.

Comment: No one starts by suing. You start with a demand letter. And a sensible person in this situation reacts to the demand letter by agreeing to remove the GPL code on a mutually agreeable schedule. And 'remove' means a 'clean enough' replacement, and 'clean enough' requires a lawyer.

Comment: Fair enough. I probably stressed the "suing" part to draw attention o the fact that the Bob was attempting to do something that the GPL may prohibit, but it might have been too sensational. A demand letter is more probable.

Comment: The third paragraph is plain wrong. Alice has to sue under the national copyright act, and "relicensing under the GPL" simply is not a legal remedy. Alice will need to sue for damages and possibly an injunction to further stop distribution altogether.